# Alternative proof of uniqueness in Problem 3.6.6 of Velleman's "How to Prove it"

Tags: elementary-set-theory, alternative-proof

I am going through Vellemen's How to prove it in my free time.
Currently I am working on problem 6 in section 3.6:
Prove that there is a unique A ∈ P(U) such that for every B ∈ P(U), A ∪ B =B.

I already guessed that the unique set sought is the empty set and there is a solution in the back of the book. But to prove uniqueness I thought whether there might be another way. So here's the outline. Suppose $A$ is not the empty set. Then there must be at least one non-trivial element in $A$, call it $x$ Since the property has to hold for all $B$ if we can find  counter example then we can show that $A$ has to be empty set. So suppose $B$ is a set which doesn't contain $x$. Then $A\cup B\neq B$. Therefore $A$ has to be the empty set. Is this a valid proof for uniqueness?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How are you sure that there is a set $B$ that does not contain $x$ ?

You can actually go much faster. Suppose $A$ and $B$ both satisfy the property. Then $$B = A \cup B = B \cup A = A.$$

Comment: Shouldn't there exist such a set because it is an element of the power set?

Comment: You would have to prove that before you could use it in your proof. One way to show such a B exists is to use  that ∅ is a subset of every set, and so is an element of every powerset. ( if you didn't know this you should try to prove it first, it's a nice exercise). Then, Let B = ∅. So, you have that B does not contain x.

Comment: @MichaelCarey Ok, so is this why the solutions used $B=\emptyset$, because that is the simplest set that doesn't contain an arbitrary element different from the empty set?

Comment: @eeqesri it's the simplest set that is also guranteed to be an element of the Powerset. Yes, that's most likely why they used it.

Comment: @eeqesri I'm a bit confused why you included "different from the empty set".  Why is that an important condition here? B = ∅ is a good choice because it is in P(U), and it doesnot contain x. ( It doenst contain any elements at all).

Comment: @MichaelCarey to your first comment: thanks I understood now the solution in the book. To the second comment: I was myself a bit unsure and confused. but my doubts are now cleared. thanks again